# MySQL COUNT() and nulls

Tags: mysql

Am I correct in saying:

```
COUNT(expr)
WHERE expr IS NOT *
```

> Will count only non nulls?

Will `COUNT(*)` always count all rows? And What if all columns are null?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Correct. COUNT(*) is all rows in the table, COUNT(Expression) is where the expression is non-null only.

If all columns are NULL (which indicates you don't have a primary key, so this shouldn't happen in a normalized database) COUNT(*) *still* returns all of the rows inserted. Just don't do that.

You can think of the * symbol as meaning "in the table" and not "in any column".

This is covered in the [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count).

Comment: Is there any way to count nulls too, with COUNT(Expression)?

Comment: If you do a COUNT( * ) then all rows are counted no matter what the contents of those rows. If you want to see both the total rows *and* the count of rows with values for SomeColumn, do a SELECT COUNT( * ) as AllRows, COUNT(SomeColumn) as SomeColumnCount. AllRows will be the total rows returned by the query, while SomeColumnCount will be the count of rows where SomeColumn had a value.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to count NULLs as well, try

```
SELECT COUNT(IFNULL(col, 1)) FROM table;
```

Comment: Great addition @Roey

Answer (score 8):

just checked:

```
select count(*)
```

returns **1** with one record filled with NULLs

```
select count(field)
```

returns **0**.

I don't see the point in the record with NULL values. Such record must not exist.

Comment: "I don't see the point in the record with NULL values". oh it just came to my mind. now when u say this i figured u are right, didnt think abt it when i asked.

Answer (score 3):

`count(*)` is not for non-null columns, it's just the way to ask to count all rows. Roughly equivalent to `count(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Using MySQL I found this simple way:

```
SELECT count(ifnull(col,1)) FROM table WHERE col IS NULL;
```

This way will not work:

```
SELECT count(col) FROM table WHERE col IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count **only** the nulls you can also use `COUNT()` with `IF`.

Example:

```
select count(*) as allRows, count(if(nullableField is null, 1, NULL)) as missing from myTable;
```

You can change the if condiditon to count what you actually want. So you can have multiple counts in one query.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select count(*) as 'total', sum(if(columna is null, 1, 0)) as 'nulos' from tabla;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).