# What difference does it make which column SQL COUNT() is run on?

Tags: mysql, sql

Firstly, this is not asking [In SQL, what's the difference between count(column) and count(*)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294/in-sql-whats-the-difference-between-countcolumn-and-count).

Say I have a `users` table with a primary key `user_id` and another field `logged_in` which describes if the user is logged in right now.

Is there a difference between running

`SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE logged_in=1`

and

`SELECT COUNT(logged_in) FROM users WHERE logged_in=1`

to see how many users are marked as logged in? Maybe a difference with indexes?

I'm running MySQL if there are DB-specific nuances to this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In MySQL, the count function will not count null expressions, so the results of your two queries may be different. As mentioned in the comments and Remus' answer, this is as a general rule for SQL and part of the [spec](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count).

For example, consider this data:

```
user_id   logged_in
1         1
null      1
```

`SELECT COUNT(user_id)` on this table will return 1, but `SELECT COUNT(logged_in)` will return 2.

As a practical matter, the results from the example in the question ought to always be the same, as long as the table is properly constructed, but the utilized indexes and query plans may differ, even though the results will be the same. Additionally, if that's a simplified example, counting on different columns may change the results as well.

See also this question: [MySQL COUNT() and nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354060/mysql-count-and-nulls)

Comment: Good answer... providing a concrete example and a related link.

Comment: I think it it worth mentioning that is a generic rule of SQL not just your MySQL

Comment: am i the only one who thinks it is not what he asked about ? as he stated it in first line

Comment: @WKordos I don't understand, would you please elaborate?

Comment: I am happy it addresses the main part of the question; I do wonder if there are any issues with performance between counting on e.g. a BOOL Vs string column or anything?

Comment: +1 this is the most important gotcha part from my answer too, and you did post it immediately :)

Comment: @John The main performance concern would be indexes. An index on a boolean column won't be useful (or exist in a well maintained DB), because it's not meaningfully selective. I don't know of any significant performance issues that would be directly caused by different data types when individually counting two columns, since count only cares whether or not the expression is null, but that of course doesn't mean that none exist.

Answer (score 5):

For the record: the two queries return different results. As the [spec](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) says:

> Returns a count of the number of **non-NULL** values of expr in the rows
>   retrieved by a SELECT statement.

You may argue that given the condition for `logged_in=1` the NULL `logged_in` rows are filtered out anyway, and `user_id` will not have NULLs in a table `users`. While this may be true, it does not change the fundamentals that the queries are different. You are asking the query optimizer to make all the logical deductions above, for you they may be obvious but for the optimizer may be is not.

Now, assuming that the results are in practice always identical between the two, the answer is simple: **don't run such a query in production** (and I mean either of them). Is a scan, no matter how you slice it. `logged_in` has too low cardinality to matter. Keep a counter, update it at each log in and each log out event. It will drift in time, refresh as often as needed (once a day, once an hour).

As for the question itself: `SELECT COUNT(somefield) FROM sometable` can use a narrow index on `somefield` resulting in less IO. The recommendation is to use `*` because this room for the optimizer to use *any* index it sees fit (this will vary from product to product though, depending on how smart a query optimizer are we dealing with, YMMV). But as you start adding WHERE clauses the possibile alternatives (=indexes to use) quickly vanish.